# How to specify date format in botium?

Tags: javascript

My expected answer from bot is current time in specific format -`"HH\\%3Amm"`

Is there a way to specify date format when using `$date`? I've tried `$date("HH\\%3Amm")` and `$date(HH\\%3Amm)` but none of them work.

If not, is there any other way to assert current time in specific format?

Comment: Why the `c#` and `.net` tags? This is a Javascript question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've eventually come up with a solution, so I will post an answer.

`$date('HH:mm')` did not work for me as I needed to validate those escape colons as well. I was validating a link, which contained current time (eg. `14%3A49`).

The way to validate turned out to be quite simple. Instead of creating a complex format as I tried before I've simply combined two validations - `$date(HH)%3A$date(mm)` and it did the trick, botium converted it to `14%3a49`.

For those who struggled with the `$date` parameterization, you don't put any quotation marks you just do `$date(DD.MM.YY)` or any other supported format and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Botium uses Moment.js for `$date` scripting function, `%3A` is just an escaped colon thus in such case `$date('HH:mm')` should work for you.

Additionally `$time_HH_MM` should have same behavior in your case.